# Who are the people in the Pit and why don't Bane, Talia and even Batman help them escape?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

During The Dark Knight Rises we find out that Ra's Al Ghul frees Bane after Talia escapes the pit.

Later we find Bane puts Batman in the pit and then leaves to take over Gotham.

Anyway, we see that there are quite a few people still in the pit, probably descendants of the first people there.

**My question is, who are these people in there and why doesn't Bane/Talia/Ra's Al Ghul (before he died)/Batman help to free them?**

I mean they helped Batman escape and the doctor helped him to heal his back to full health. These people are living in unsafe and inhumane conditions, surely Batman would at least try and find a really long ladder or something...

Being victims of the pit themselves, I mean Bane did everything he could to save Talia so surely he/Talia would feel sympathy for the people living in there...

Comment: What will the point of a prison with no prisoners?

Comment: Wait so who put the prisoners there? If it was a prison whats the point of a putting a escape mechanism in it? Even then why does Batman not help these people? I mean they kinda helped him escape.. Especially the doctor..

Comment: Batman throws a long rope back down to the people once he escapes.

Comment: @MetroBoomin The point of the escape mechanism was to give the people false hope. It was not supposed to be useable.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Who are these people?

They're prisoners. The Pit is a prison:

> **The Pit** is a prison located in the ancient part of the world, which had established such a fearsome reputation that it became referred to as "the worst Hell on Earth".

#### Why doesn't Bane/Talia/Ra's Al Ghul (before he died)/Batman help to free them?

**Bane, Talia and Ra's Al Ghul:**

How could they free them, the prisoners were the ones that killed Ra's Al Ghul's wife (Talia's mother) and disfigured Bane:

> Approximately 30 years before the events of The Dark Knight Rises, a young mercenary was sentenced to be imprisoned within this Pit for falling in love with the daughter of the warlord he worked for. Unbeknownst to the mercenary, however, the warlord's daughter arranged for his release under the condition that she take his place in The Pit. Also unknown to him was that she was pregnant with the mercenary's child and she gave birth inside the prison walls. She named their daughter Talia. Many years later, **the warlord's daughter was attacked and killed by the other inmates**. Talia, however, was protected by a fellow prisoner known as Bane, a man who spent his entire life in the prison.
>
> Bane later aided in Talia's escape from the prison, **which lead to his disfigurement through severe beatings**. Bane was then treated by the prison doctor and heavily bandaged. Following Talia's escape from the prison, she located her former mercenary father, Ra's al Ghul, and he returned with the League of Shadows to exact revenge upon the prisoners who had killed the love of his life.

What better revenge than to keep them in there.

**Batman/Bruce Wayne:**

Bruce Wayne did actually help them: After he successfuly climbed out, he threw down a rope so the other inmates could climb it and go free.

#### How do the people down in the pit get food and water?

Read this [scifi.stackexchange.com question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100888/who-was-feeding-the-prisoners-of-the-pit-in-the-dark-knight-rises).

---

<sup>**Note:** All the quotes are taken from [Batman Wikia#The Pit](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/The_Pit).</sup>